# How mock a function in mockito?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit5

i have a function and i want mock it for to do anothers operations:
I write this (java 8) but i have error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

my code is this:

```
public class ApplicationTest {

@Mock
MqttService mqttServiceMock;
@Mock
ElasticService elasticServiceMock;
@Mock
RestTemplate restTemplateMock;

private String message_out;
private String response_condition;
private boolean condition;

@Test
public void measureChannelProcessor() throws IOException {
    ElasticConfiguration elasticConfiguration = null;
    String resp=new ObjectMapper().readTree(this.getClass().getResource("/respElasticInsert.json")).toString();

    when(restTemplateMock.postForEntity(anyString(), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(String.class)))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(resp,HttpStatus.OK));

    when(elasticServiceMock.insert(anyString(),anyString())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
        String index = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        String message = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];

        String requestUri = new StringBuilder()
                .append(elasticConfiguration.baseRequestBuilder(index))
                .toString();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(message, headers);
        restTemplateMock = elasticConfiguration.customRestTemplate();
        return restTemplateMock.postForEntity(requestUri, requestEntity, String.class);
    });

   doReturn((MessageHandler) message -> {
       String index = "measure";
       ResponseEntity<String> res = null;
       message_out= message.getPayload().toString();
       boolean checkMeasure = JsonUtility.checkMeasure(message_out);
       if (checkMeasure ){
           res = elasticServiceMock.insert(index, message_out);
       }
       System.out.println(res);
   }).when(mqttServiceMock).measureChannelProcessor(); 

    JsonNode measureJsonTest = new ObjectMapper().readTree(this.getClass().getResource("/MeasureTest.json"));
    mqttServiceMock.measureChannelProcessor().handleMessage(new GenericMessage<>(measureJsonTest.toString()));


}
```

there are 3 function mock.

when is running:

```
**res = elasticServiceMock.insert(index, message_out);**
```

i have Error java.lang.NullPointerException but i have mocked  elasticServiceMock.insert function.

Why? where is the problem?

Thanks for tips

Regards

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Also, it is not clear what is your object under test and how elasticServiceMock instance is provided to that object

Comment: Also, please show all import statements to make sure you are using the right annotations.

Comment: this part: String resp=new ObjectMapper().readTree(this.getClass().getResource("/respElasticInsert.json")).toString();
when(restTemplateMock.postForEntity(anyString(), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(resp,HttpStatus.OK));

dont work, and i have this error:

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at it.anas.communication.ApplicationTest.lambda$measureChannelProcessor$0(ApplicationTest.java:61)
 at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.StubbedInvocationMatcher.answer(StubbedInvocation

Process finished with exit code -1

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the full stacktrace and not a shortened one. 

Also if you would post your whole code not just the test

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `@Mock` Annotation you need to have your Test class annotated with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`.

Like that:

```
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ApplicationTest {
```